# What is the difference between "a memoir" and "a biography"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between "a memoir" and "a biography"?

According to my study, "a biography of a person A" is normally written by someone else not A and "a memoir of a person A" is normally written by A himself.

Also, "a biography" is quite detailed from birth to death while "a memoir" is not too detailed.

Comment: "Autobiography" is the reasonably complete biography written by the subject of the book.  "Memoir" is an autobiography that is less complete/more biased.

Comment: Agreeing with @HotLicks. For instance, a memoir of a US president might start with his time in Congress and discuss significant policy decisions he made during his time in office. 
Or to put it in movie terms, an autobiography would be portrayed as a documentary, while a memoir would be portrayed as a drama, focusing on several turning points.

Comment: Memoir vs. Autobiography: What’s the Difference? https://www.grammarly.com/blog/memoir-vs-autobiography/#:~:text=A%20memoir%20is%20a%20nonfiction,life%20from%20beginning%20to%20end.